# Distribute matlab functions without source

Tags: matlab, shared

I have written a set of Matlab functions and I want to distribute it to few people for testing. But I do not want to reveal the source to them. All these people have matalb installed on their systems. So I don't want to make standalone executable from my functions. Ideally I want something like complied library files which the users can put in the matlab path & call the functions from their matlab prompt / matlab functions. Is it even possible ?

Edit: I have  matlab compiler toolbox. But the users won't be having access to matlab compiler toolbox on their matlab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way is using `pcode`. Look in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/pcode.html) and remember to keep a copy of the source code elsewhere!